# Jetpack Compose theming at runtime from network api call

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an API call for theming that returns all colors for my application. I want to apply these colors all of jetpack components. can anyone please suggest a proper way to do this.

I have two files theme. kt and color. kt .

I need to change values in these classes dynamically.

Comment: if your themes are static and they never gonna change you can keep them in your app get the current theme from api.

Comment: @MohammadBaqer can you please suggest proper way ?

Comment: App sample from Google with dynamic theming: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetcaster

Answer (score 1):

you should receive your colors from API then store that in dataStore then observe your data store in the main theme compose function whenever colors changed then create a new color pallet then set that in your MaterialTheme. automatically everywhere used MaterialTheme colors are updated.

Comment: could you please share sample project?